# Express routing gives 404 for url's apart from localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

My application currently serves fine making calls with Express, but I have a page now rendered by:

```
app.get('/user/:username', function(req, res){
  serve html page (no problems)
}
```

and from that page, I'm making a request for

```
return $http.get('/api/user/:s').success(function (resp) {
  stuff...
}
```

which is returning a 404 not found.

The call is in my Express app.js as

```
app.get('/api/user/:username', routes.api.getDBUser);
```

and I've been stumped on this problem for ages now. I feel like the issue is from something related to the URL.

**EDIT:**

```
app.use("/user", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static'))); //serving statics for localhost/user paths

app.get('/api/user', authentication.isAuthenticated, routes.api.getUser);
app.get('/api/users/:username', routes.api.getDBUser);
app.get('/api/user/friends', authentication.isAuthenticated, routes.api.getUserFriends);
app.get('/api/user/history', authentication.isAuthenticated, routes.api.getUserGameHistory);
```

is all the routes related to the user here. I'm not sure if this has something to do with it, but accessing a routing call when the url is something like `localhost(port)/something`, it's okay. The URL at this particular page I'm trying to make the call from is `localhost(port)/user/something`

Comment: Does `routes.api.getDBUser` send back an explicit 404 when it cannot find the username in the database?

Comment: @robertklep It seems to not even execute the command, as if it can't even find the route.

Comment: It may be caused by your route/app setup, especially if you have other routes that may also match that same path. Can you add the other routes you're declaring for your app (in the order in which you declare them, which is important)?

Comment: @robertklep updated OP

Comment: Uhm do you notice the typo...?

Comment: @robertklep I changed the request from `:s` to just `s` and it still is giving me a 404.

Comment: It says `/api/users/:username`, plural "users", not singular "user", in the route that should be passed to `routes.api.getDBUser`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141246/discussion-between-helpisgood-and-robertklep).